# Word macro cannot save filename > 255 characters

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this in my Word Macro

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="D:\\GrooveAndRock\\GrooveAndRock\\GrooveAndRock\\GrooveAndRock\\GrooveAndRock\\GrooveAndRock\\GrooveAndRockAndRoll\\GrooveAndRockAndRoll\\GrooveAndRockAndRoll\\GrooveAndRockAndRoll\\GrooveAndRockAndRoll\\GrooveAndRockAndRoll\\Ug F Blug and Bug f Goo - Blank Address - 2009-09-25 093614.doc", FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument, _
     LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword _
    :="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _
    SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:= _
    False
```

(note the long filename)

When I run it, I get :
"Run-time error '9105':

String is longer than 255 characters"

Is it really the case that word automation cannot save long filenames? This is a pretty serious limitation, yet a google search on the error has brought up nothing..

Is there a workaround?

Whats going on!??!?

Confused..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using dir function to get into the folder you want and then save it:

```vb
ChDir "D:\\GrooveAndRock\\GrooveAndRock\\GrooveAndRock\\GrooveAndRock\\GrooveAndRock\\GrooveAndRock\\GrooveAndRockAndRoll\\GrooveAndRockAndRoll\\GrooveAndRockAndRoll\\GrooveAndRockAndRoll\\GrooveAndRockAndRoll\\GrooveAndRockAndRoll\\"

ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="Ug F Blug and Bug f Goo - Blank Address - 2009-09-25 093614.doc", _
    FileFormat:=...
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a limitation in Windows:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#maximum_path_length

Comment: Wow, you are right. I remember this from my Windows 95 days now! 14 years later and they still havent sorted it out...

Answer (score 1):

That is it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw949162.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround this by converting the path to the old 8.3 format:

```vb
    strFolder = "D:\GrooveAndRock\GrooveAndRock\GrooveAndRock\GrooveAndRock\GrooveAndRock\GrooveAndRock\GrooveAndRockAndRoll\GrooveAndRockAndRoll\GrooveAndRockAndRoll\GrooveAndRockAndRoll\GrooveAndRockAndRoll\GrooveAndRockAndRoll"
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs _
        FileName:=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder(strFolder).ShortPath & "Ug F Blug and Bug f Goo - Blank Address - 2009-09-25 093614.doc", _
        FileFormat:=...
```